# fromJson and toJson not generated when the build code is put in build.yaml file

Tags: flutter, json-serialization, json-serializable, build-runner

If I use the following code in `pubspec.yaml` file, then the `build_runner` generates code but if I put it in the `build.yaml` file, then the code is not generated for `fromJson` and `toJson`.

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      json_serializable:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          include:
            - lib/foo.dart
```

I also want to know, whether I include (or not include) any files above, the code takes same amount of time to generate. So, how can I then generate the code for a specific file/directory, like first generate for `foo.dart` and later on I want to generate code for `bar.dart` keeping `foo.dart` and `foo.g.dart` intact.

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing this code in `build.yaml` then yes, `build_runner` use it as configuration and will generate a files that you include in your config. If you are placing this code in `pubspec.yaml` file `build_runner` will not use it because `pubspec.yaml` doesn't config file for `build_runner`.

When you are working with `build_runner` you can listend and rebuild any changes automatically with `watch` argument:

```bash
flutter pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Comment: So, what should I do so that I can write those rules in a `build.yaml` file?

Comment: @iDecode, you can find some examples at https://wilsonwilson.dev/articles/flutter-build-yaml.